# Understanding .bind() in relation to arguments

Tags: javascript, this, bind, requestanimationframe

I am reviewing some game code and I have a piece that I don't quite understand.

```
var game = (function(){

   // Start with our constructor
   function Game(){
        this.viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        this.ctx = this.viewport.getContext('2d');
    };

    Game.prototype.updateAnimation = function(t){

        // work out the delta time
        this.dt = this.lastFrameTime ? ((t - this.lastFrameTime)/1000.0).fixed() : 0.016;

        // store last frame time
        this.lastFrameTime = t;

        // run relevent updates here

        // queue the next animation time.
        this.animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame( this.updateAnimation.bind(this), this.viewport );
    }

    // return game class
    return Game;

})();
```

Then

```
// call new game object
var clientGame = new game();

// call event loop
clientGame.updateAnimation(new Date().getTime());
```

When request `window.requestAnimationFrame( this.updateAnimation.bind(this), this.viewport );` runs. How does it know the value of the paramter `t`. It seems to update each time, but I don't understand why. Can someone please explain whats going on? Thanks.

## EDIT

There is a function attached to the `Number` prototype chain called `fixed()`. Here it is for clarity

```
 Number.prototype.fixed = function(n) { n = n || 3; return parseFloat(this.toFixed(n)); };
```

Comment: that's odd ... requestAnimationFrame only accepts a single argument - wonder what the author thinks passing a second argument will do

Comment: do you mean .toFixed() instead of fixed()?

Comment: @JaromandaX There is a weird polyfill for `requestionAnimationFrame` by paul irish seen [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). The code is from 2012

Comment: @magreenberg think you answered your own question there... it is calculating and passing `t` to the callback

Comment: @karthick See Edit for info on `.fixed()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `requestAnimationFrame` has one parameter, a callback which gets a timestamp as argument.
The bind function returns the original function but in a different scope. So `requestAnimationFrame` calls updateAnimation with the timestamp, which is where your time is coming from.

Now to understand the reasoning behind the `bind` call you need to understand scopes in JavaScript.

When you're defining a function and passing it to another function as a parameter you're actually calling the first function in the scope of the second. This means if you have a class instance and you wanna pass an instance method to a function as a callback you either need to use an arrow function which preserves the current scope or you bind the method to the correct scope (your class instance).

I hope the following example better shows what I'm talking about.

```
class OuterScope {
    constructor() {
        this.label = 'test';
    }

    print() {
        console.log(this.label);
    }
}

function innerScope(callback) {
    callback();
}

var scope = new OuterScope();
innerScope(scope.print); // throws error because the scope the function is called in doesn't have a property called label
innerScope(scope.print.bind(scope)); // prints label
```

Now apply this to your `requestAnimationFrame` problem:

```
class Game {
    updateAnimation(t) {
        // this.lastFrameTime would always be undefined when called without binding
        this.dt = this.lastFrameTime ? ((t - this.lastFrameTime)/1000.0).fixed() : 0.016;

        // store last frame time
        this.lastFrameTime = t;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnimation.bind(this)); // updateAnimation now always runs in the scope of the current Game instance
        // window.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateAnimation); // updateAnimation runs in the scope of the window
    }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame = function requestAnimationFrame(callback) {
    callback(new Date().getTime()); // calls the callback with one argument
}
```

Comment: Both answers are basically the same, but this one helped me understand more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the code could be written better, there is no need to bind the function all over again each time, it's enough to do it once (for example during the initialization of the object)

Secondly, the function `requestAnimationFrame` accepts one argument only, so there is no meaning to the second one, and the first argument is the `t` which sent by the browser to the callback.

The method `.bind` doesn't change the function arguments (maybe except `arguments.callee` though this is redundant) but only the `context` of the function so the first argument stays `t` (the `timestamp`)

more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

**Edit**

So the user is using some polyfill which allows to send two arguments to requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I agree but according to OP's comment. [this polyfill](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) is in use. I suggest you edit it

Comment: Basically, it knows value of `t` because `t` is supplied by `requestAnimationFrame` at the moment it's called.

Comment: @suraj, tnx - just saw it, and yet it doesn't change a lot.

Comment: so `t` is a value native to `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: t is the `timestamp` provided to the callback, native yes.

Comment: Do I understand this right.... By default, the callback of `requestAnimationFrame()` passes a [DOMTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTimeStamp) as a parameter? I am just using `t` to access the value and explicitly set it for the first function call.

Comment: `t` is the current timestamp always, sent by the browser, within `this.lastFrameTime` the last `t` is stored. (from the prev triggered callback)